# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘haven’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

Tags: r, centos, r-haven

I am not able to open install the 'haven' packages. It gives me the following error:

```
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘haven’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/home/R/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/haven/libs/haven.so':
/home/R/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/haven/libs/haven.so:undefined symbol: libiconv
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/R/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/haven’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘haven’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp4y5PTv/downloaded_packages’
```

**I have also tried to remove and re-install it, but without success.**

```
install.packages('haven', dep = TRUE)
```

Comment: The error is telling you there is a problem with *libiconv*, your system is likely missing the dependency.

Comment: On redhat, apparently this is packaged with the std C libraries. Do you have `glibc-devel` installed? If not, `yum install glibc-devel` may resolve (though you'll likely need to reinstall `haven` if you built from source)

Comment: glibc-devel  already installed and latest version.